# Padding a string in Postgresql with rpad without truncating it

Tags: sql, string, function, postgresql, string-formatting

Using Postgresql 8.4, how can I right-pad a string with blanks *without* truncating it when it's too long?

The problem is that `rpad` *truncates* the string when it is actually longer than number of characters to pad. Example:

```
SELECT rpad('foo', 5);  ==> 'foo  ' -- fine
SELECT rpad('foo', 2);  ==> 'fo'    -- not good, I want 'foo' instead.
```

The shortest solution I found doesn't involve `rpad` at all:

```
SELECT 'foo' || repeat(' ', 5-length('foo'));  ==> 'foo  ' -- fine
SELECT 'foo' || repeat(' ', 2-length('foo'));  ==> 'foo'   -- fine, too
```

but this looks ugly IMHO. Note that I don't actually select the string 'foo' of course, instead I select from a column:

```
SELECT colname || repeat(' ', 30-length(colname)) FROM mytable WHERE ...
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

found a slightly more elegant solution:

```
SELECT greatest(colname,rpad(colname, 2));
```

eg:

```
SELECT greatest('foo',rpad('foo', 5));  -- 'foo  ' 
SELECT greatest('foo',rpad('foo', 2));  -- 'foo'
```

.

---

To explain how it works: 
rpad('foo',5) = 'foo  ' which is > 'foo' (greatest works with strings as well as numbers)
rpad('foo',2) = 'fo' which is < 'foo', so 'foo' is selected by greatest function.

if you want left-padded words you cant use greatest because it compares left-to-right (eg 'oo' with 'foo') and in some cases this will be greater or smaller depending on the string. I suppose you could reverse the string and use the rpad and reverse it back, or just use the original solution which works in both cases.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to write that `repeat` business all the time, just write your own function for it. Something like this:

```
create or replace function rpad_upto(text, int) returns text as $$
begin
    if length($1) >= $2 then
        return $1;
    end if;
    return rpad($1, $2);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

or this:

```
create or replace function rpad_upto(text, int) returns text as $$
select $1 || repeat(' ', $2 - length($1));
$$ language sql;
```

Then you can say things like:

```
select rpad_upto(colname, 30) from mytable ...
```

You might want to consider what you want `rpad_upto(null, n)` to produce while you're at it. Both versions of `rpad_upto` above will return NULL if `$1` is NULL but you can tweak them to return something else without much difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would work, but db admins do not allow me to create new functions (at least not for such a trivial task, only when absolutely neccessary).

Answer (score 4):

how about this

```
select case when length(col) < x then rpad(col, x)
else col
end
from table
```

Comment: Nice, but 8 chars more than mine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming efficiency is not your biggest concern here:

```
select regexp_replace(format('%5s', 'foo'), '(\s*)(\S*)', '\2\1')
```

1. format() left-pads the string to the desired width
2. then regexp_replace moves any leading spaces to the end.

I guess that would fail if you have leading spaces in the strings and you want to preserve them. Also note that format() doesn't return null on null params.

Comment: Simply `select format('%-5s', 'foo')` would give the same result.

Comment: this feature appears to be unavailable in versions prior to 9.3

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL statement below is to right pad three place values and alter column data type to text for column 'columnname.' I used pycharm IDE to help construct statement. The statement will pad with 000.

I have been looking for a while to solve the same issue, except for left pad and I thought I would share.

```
alter table 'schema.tablename' alter column 'columnname' type text using rpad('columnname'::text,3,'0')
```